# Right clicking a button inflates AppBar instead of firing right click event

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

So I have a button in my AppBar that adds buttons to a stackpanel that is located in a grid on the page.
I assigned a RightTapped event to the new buttons.
However, when I right click a new button, instead of firing the method I assigned to the RightTapped event, the program inflates the AppBar.
I tried to set IsRightTapEnabled="False" one every item but the new buttons, but that didn't help the issue.
I'm stuck and I need help.

Here is my code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    int index = 0;

    private void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        index++;
        string ButtonName = "Button" + index;
        Button dummyButton = new Button
        {
            Name = ButtonName,
            Content = ButtonName,
        };
        StackPanel1.Children.Add(dummyButton);
        dummyButton.RightTapped += new RightTappedEventHandler(DummyButton_RightTapped);
    }

    private void Button0_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuFlyout myFlyout = new MenuFlyout();
        MenuFlyoutItem firstItem = new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "Right Clicked" };

        myFlyout.Items.Add(firstItem);
        myFlyout.ShowAt(sender as FrameworkElement);
    }

    private void DummyButton_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //var dialog = new MessageDialog("Right clicked");
        //await dialog.ShowAsync();

        MenuFlyout myFlyout = new MenuFlyout();
        MenuFlyoutItem firstItem = new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "Right Clicked" };

        myFlyout.Items.Add(firstItem);
        myFlyout.ShowAt(sender as FrameworkElement);
    }
}
```

Here is my XAML code:

```
<Page
x:Class="Soundboard.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Soundboard"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
IsRightTapEnabled="False">

<Page.TopAppBar >
    <AppBar IsSticky="True" IsRightTapEnabled="False" >
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <AppBarButton Label="Add Sound" Icon="OpenFile" Click="AppBarButton_Click" ></AppBarButton>
        </StackPanel>
    </AppBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>

<Grid Background="#FF004D40" Name="myGrid" IsRightTapEnabled="False">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Name="StackPanel1" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" IsRightTapEnabled="False">
        <Button Content="Button0" Name ="Button0" RightTapped="Button0_RightTapped"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official does not recommend using the `AppBar` in UWP. The following section references Official [AppBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar) instructions.

> You should use the [AppBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar) only when you are upgrading a Universal Windows 8 app that uses the AppBar, and need to minimize changes. For new apps in Windows 10, we recommend using the CommandBar control instead.

**Usage**

Add `CommandBar` to `<Page.TopAppBar>` just like following code.

```
 <Page.TopAppBar>
        <CommandBar IsSticky="True">
            <AppBarButton
                Click="AppBarButton_Click"
                Icon="OpenFile"
                Label="Add Sound" />              
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.TopAppBar>
```